# Angularjs issue in relacing Ajax request with promises in service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

For my Angularjs application in services I have used Ajax call to get the data and is as follows :

```
var originalRequest = $.ajax({
                    async : false,
                    url : "/dash/dashboard2ajax.do",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : {
                        action : 'getNetSpendOverTime',
                        customerId : selectedAccTd,
                        carriersId : selectedCarriers,
                        fromDate : formattedFromDate,
                        toDate : formattedToDate
                    },
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(originalRequest) {
                        var res = originalRequest;
                        data = res.ResultSet.Response;

                    }
                });
```

Then I just return (data) from my service and in my controller I am able to get data without any problem. But I realized it is a bad practice and trying to use promises. So I have replaced it as follows:

```
var originalRequest = $http({
            url: "/dash/dashboard2ajax.do",
            method: "POST",
            data: {action : 'getNetSpendOverTime',
                customerId : selectedAccTd,
                carriersId : selectedCarriers,
                fromDate : formattedFromDate,
                toDate : formattedToDate}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           return (data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return(status);
        });
```

But it is not working. None of the parameters are getting even passed to my action class. Is there any mistake in my syntax?

In my action class, I am accessing the parameters as

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
```

But it is coming as null.

Comment: first change action name to other name and try

Comment: sorry, do you mean something like,  actiontest : 'getNetSpendOverTime'

Comment: yes make action as actiontest and check

Comment: No luck, same problem, it is coming as null.

Comment: I have tested this change with my normal ajax request without using promises, then it is fine. String action1 = request.getParameter("actiontest"); But with promises, it always shows null. I cleared browser cache, deployed server cache, etc but still it is showing null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to replace `jQuery.ajax` with AngularJS `$http`, which has completely different contract. The thing you're calling `originalRequest` is not in fact any kind of "request object". It's just a `Promise` (extended with `success` and `error` methods). If you want to access the request data outside your success/error handlers, you need to save and pass it separately yourself:

```
var data = {
    // ...
};
var request = $http({
    data: data,
    // ...
});
return {
    request: request,
    data: data
};
```

If you need to access it inside the handlers, just get it from the `config` argument:

```
$http(...).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var action = config.data.action;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: If you're coming from `jQuery` background and trying to learn AngularJS, you need to really read some [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), not just expect things to work like in `jQuery` (they don't). You might try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542).