# Turn request success into error based on response data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I am relatively new to Angular js and trying to use promises along with services and got reference http://plnkr.co/edit/b4HPbX2olM745EfHVcc6?p=preview. But in my application I am getting response as {"Response":"exception while loading Reports List","error":"Exception getting all records.","status":"failure"}. When I get response like this, I need to show an alert message with the message in "error" (i.e., Exception getting all records) and set $scope.data to [] in my controller.What are the changes I need to make to services and controller to handle this. Any help is much appreciated.

In services :

```
return $q.when(originalRequest)
          .then(function(res) {
            data = res.ResultSet.Response;
            return data;
          });
```

In Controller,

```
  DashboardsDataService.getNetSpendOverTimeData()
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
      });
```

The following is my original request to Java action class:

```
var originalRequest = $.ajax({
                            async : false,
                            url : "/dash2/dashd2ajax.do",
                            type : "POST",
                            data : {
                                action : 'getNetSpendOverTime',
                                customerId : selectedAccTd,
                                carriersId : selectedCarriers,
                                fromDate : fromDate,
                                toDate : toDate,
                                modes : selectedModes,
                                services : selectedServices,
                                dateType : selectedDateType,
                                lanesList : selectedLaneList
                            },
                            dataType : "json"
                        });
                 return $q.when(originalRequest)
                  .then(function(res) {
                    data = res.ResultSet.Response;
                    return data;
                  });
```

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)?

Comment: Yes and I even made the changes to services as,     return $q.when(originalRequest)
          .then(function(res) {
            data = res.ResultSet.Response;
            return data;
          }, function(err){
            alert( err.ResultSet.error);
            data = [];
            return data;
          });. But it is not working as I expected. Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: Please show where the `originalRequest` comes from.

Comment: I have updated the question with the originalRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're asking is "how do I turn request success into a failure based on result data", then take a look at the following example:

```
return $q.when(originalRequest).then(function (res) {
    if (res.ResultSet.error) {
        return $q.reject(res.ResultSet.error);
    } else {
        return res.ResultSet.Response;
    }
});
```

Using `$q.reject()` turned your data into a real "promise failure", so in your controller, you can use the normal promise API:

```
doSomethingAsynchronous().then(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
}, function (error) {
    $scope.data = [];
    alert(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for. Do you have any pointers for me to a similar issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057909/angularjs-issue-in-relacing-ajax-request-with-promises-in-service?rq=1        to use http service.